# Using yiidocsgenerator extension to generate documentation

Tags: documentation, yii, yii-extensions

I posted in the Yii forum with no luck. I am hoping someone in this community got this extension working because I really need it!

I used the yiic docs check command, and all the models seem to finally pass the check. So, I proceeded to executing this command:

```
yiic docs C:\path to my site\protected\models
```

And at first this appears onscreen:

```
Building.. : MyApplication Class Reference
Version... : 1.1.7
Source URL:
```

And then this error pops up:

```
Building model...
PHP Error[2]:include<GxActiveRecord.php>: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in file C:\path-to-my-app\yii\framework\YiiBase.php at line 396
```

Where, at that line, I have the following code:

```
include($className.'.php');
```

I don't understand why it is looking for a class I do not have!! I found it [here](http://code.google.com/p/giix/source/browse/trunk/giix/components/GxActiveRecord.php?r=175), but I don't know in what specific folder that class should reside, or better yet why I should have to download it separately when it's not specified in the instructions. Thanks.

Comment: Turn on error logging to file, and check the backtrace of that error. You will see the call trace, and you can deduct where that class is required. Or just search your code base to locate that class. Probably it was generated using the giix tool and later the tool was removed.

Comment: @Pentium10 How do I turn on error logging to file?

Comment: Google it, there are plenty of articles on yii logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've generated models from giix which have GxActiveRecord as a base class and the doc parser does not find this base class, usually you've defined this as an import in your application config, so this may be an expected behavior.

You could try importing something like 'ext.giix.components.GxActiveRecord' in every one of your model classes  or copy GxActiveRecord into your models directory just for generating the docs.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much, I copied the GxActiveRecord class into my models directory and the problem was solved!